# Java JNA OpenFileById fails with error code 87 InvalidParameter

Tags: java, winapi, filesystems, jna

I'm trying to get file **HANDLE** by NTFS file id.

1. Having file HANLDE I'm getting **FILE_ID_INFO**

```java
Memory p = new Memory(128);
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetFileInformationByHandleEx(
    hFile, 
    WinBase.FileIdInfo,
    p,
    new DWORD(p.size())
);
FILE_ID_INFO fii = new FILE_ID_INFO(p);
```

From FILE_ID_INFO I can get **VolumeSerialNumber** and **FileId.Identifier**

2. Now when I have that - I want to open HANDLE using VolumeSerialNumber and FileId.Identifier
3. First using **Kernel32Util.getLogicalDriveStrings()** and **Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetVolumeInformation** I can find VolumeId by VolumeSerialNumber - which in my case would be D:\
4. Now I open HANDLE for D:\ using **Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile**

```java
Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(
    path,
    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
    1 | 2 | 4,
    null,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    null
)
```

5. And last step - using [OpenFileById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilebyid) I'm trying open file HANDLE by its id.
   Method definition

```java
HANDLE OpenFileById(
    HANDLE hVolumeHint,
    Structure lpFileId,
    int dwDesiredAccess,
    int dwShareMode,
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    int dwFlagsAndAttributes
);
```

Required structure

```java
@FieldOrder({"dwSize", "Type", "Id"})
public static class FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR extends Structure {

    public UINT dwSize;
    public int Type;
    public DUMMYUNIONNAME Id;

    @FieldOrder({"FileId", "ObjectId", "ExtendedFileId"})
    public static class DUMMYUNIONNAME extends Union {

        public long FileId;
        public GUID ObjectId;
        public FILE_ID_128 ExtendedFileId;

        public DUMMYUNIONNAME() {
             super();
        }

        public DUMMYUNIONNAME(long Id) {
            this.FileId = Id;
            write();
        }
    }

    public static UINT sizeOf() {
        return new UINT(Native.getNativeSize(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR.class, null));
    }

    public FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR() {
        super();
    }

    public FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR(Pointer memory) {
        super(memory);
        read();
    }

    public FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR(UINT dwSize, int type,
            DUMMYUNIONNAME id) {
        this.dwSize = dwSize;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Id = id;
        write();
    }
}
```

Usage

```java
FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR fileIdDesc = new FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR.sizeOf(), 0, new DUMMYUNIONNAME(fii.FileId.Identifier));
HANDLE handle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenFileById(hVolume, fileIdDesc, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, 1 | 2 | 4, null, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS);
```

When I after executing
**Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();**
It gives me - 87 Invalid Parameter.

I've change FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR to accept long instead of byte[], and other changes - but everytime - same error.

Similar code works successfully in C#, but I need it to run in Java as well.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure your union is modeled correctly.  Where is `FILE_ID_128` defined, and does it actually allocate 128 bits even if you're only assigning a value to the 64-bit member?

Comment: @DanielWiddis, this what you see in the post - is the last version I was trying. The DUMMYUNIONNAME was Structure, Pointer, there were NO DUMMYUNIONNAME, but just Id, etc. I was trying from 4 - to 512 bits - error code never changed. I'm desperate actually to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've incorrectly initialized your `FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR` values:

```java
new FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR(
   FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR.sizeOf(),
   0,
   new DUMMYUNIONNAME(fii.FileId.Identifier)
);
```

You're passing the `Type` parameter as 0, indicating you want the `long FileId` from the union.

But you have hardcoded your dummy union constructor to assign the value to the 8-byte `long` member when the value of `fii.FileId.Identifier` is a 16-byte array.

You've indicated in the comments that:

> this what you see in the post - is the last version I was trying. The DUMMYUNIONNAME was Structure, Pointer, there were NO DUMMYUNIONNAME, but just Id, etc. I was trying from 4 - to 512 bits - error code never changed.

There is exactly one right answer and it's 16 bytes (128 bits).  However, if you pass a `Type` of 0, it's only reading the first 8 bytes (64 bits) of your `fii.FileId.Identifier`.

Most likely you want to set/read the `ExtendedFileId` field in the union, by setting a `Type` of 2.

There are several other issues with your code that are not the cause of the error:

1. You are over-allocating memory when creating the `FILE_ID_INFO` by giving 128 bytes to `p`.  You haven't shown your mapping for it, but it's an 8-byte `long` followed by a structure wrapping a 16-byte array so you only need 24 bytes.
2. You don't need to implement your own `sizeOf()`.  JNA's `Structure` has a `size()` method that does exactly what you're asking.  Or you can just use your knowledge that in this case the size is always 24.
3. The `dwSize` field of `FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR` is a `DWORD` not a `UINT`.  Since these are both 32-bit values it doesn't make a difference.  Since Java does not have a concept of signed integers you may as well just simplify and pass an `int` here.
4. If you want to actually leverage JNA's `Union` class you should fully implement it including overriding the `read()` in the union to read the appropriate native value.  In your case, you're only writing it for use once, so you can just skip the complexity of the union and directly assign the internal field you want.  If that's the largest size value (the `FILE_ID_128`) you can just assign it directly. If it's a smaller size value (the `long` then you could just add padding to make sure the entire structure size is 24 bytes).

Comment: Thank you so much for your advises. I will check as soon as get to laptop.
You are right, FileId.Identifier is byte[], but it is possible to change it to long and it will still work - JNA can assign proper long to it whish corresponds to the byte[]. Not sure if that is correct approach, but it works.

Comment: Hi. I don't know how and main question why - but it works. I changed nothing, but it does)
I changed my FILE_ID_128 when I read file Id to read it to long.
I changed the dwSize to 128 - and now it works. But I'm sure I tested that already and it didn't. This is Murphy law looks like.
Thanks so much for the hints.

Comment: From JNA's perspective it's just bytes. It's what the native OS does with it that matters. If the first 8 bytes of the 16-byte array encode a long, it would work either way.